# Append pd.value_counts() and defined variable to a row of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Had a bit of difficulty coming up with a simple example, but I hope this makes sense: I have a loop that generates me a variable `name` and a dataframe like so

```
name = 'store1'
exampledf = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['bird', 'bird', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat']})
```

I can use `exampledf['animal'].value_counts()` to get:

```
cat     3
bird    2
dog     1
```

Desired output is to add the `name` and value counts to a new df like so:

```
store    cat    bird    dog
store1   3      2       1
```

Then on the next loop say I have

```
name = 'store2'
exampledf = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['cat', 'cat', 'bird', 'cat', 'cat', 'bird']})
```

I'd want that to add on to get:

```
store    cat    bird    dog
store1   3      2       1
store2   4      2       0
```

I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Will you ever be adding new types of animals in a subsequent dataframes?

Comment: No, although the first dataframe might not have all animals, so the initial dataframe would have to have `cat`, `bird`, `dog` as column names even if the first iteration only had a count for `cat` and 0 for `bird/dog`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try vectorizing this. Concatenate your DataFrames, call `str.get_dummies` and then sum along the index.

```
df_list = [exampledf1, exampledf2]
names = [name1, name2]

(pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, keys=names)
   .animal
   .str.get_dummies()
   .sum(level=0)
)

        bird  cat  dog
store1     2    3    1
store2     2    4    0
```

If your data isn't in the format of `df_list` & `names`, I strongly recommend finding a way to get it there.

---

The alternative is to call `df.append` per loop iteration. I consider this to be slow and ugly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for d, n in zip(df_list, names):
    df = df.append(
        d.animal.value_counts().to_frame().T.set_index([[n]])
    )

df
        bird  cat  dog
store1     2    3  1.0
store2     2    4  NaN
```

Comment: Each df is generated in a loop thousands of times - so instead of `exampledf1, exampledf2`, I have just `exampledf` and `name` which are rewritten on the next loop. That's why I was thinking an ability to append a new row to a global df at the end of each loop would be the way to go.

Comment: @Liquidity Initialise two lists outside a loop and append at each iteration. In the end, generate this result. The alternatively is slow and ugly.

Comment: @Liquidity added the ugly alternative to my answer, btw.